# Fast find multiple of 4

Tags: c++, integer

Is there a fast way to find if a 32-bit integer is a multiple of 4 without using the % operator (In C++)?

Comment: If you want to C++ solution, why do you has tagged C?

Comment: Why not use the `%` operator? When you have a tool that's specifically designed for precisely the task at hand, you have to wonder when someone specifically insists you not use it.

Comment: I thought that the % operator would be slow because it uses divide (I think?)

Comment: @TomTetlaw: Compilers are written by smart people. If the language presents a clean, simple, direct, obvious way to do something, why would you assume it would be badly implemented? On a version of GCC I just tested on, `return (c%4) == 0;` and `return (c & 3) ==0;` produce identical code. The compiler knows they're equivalent. Both became two assembly instructions, `andl` then `sete`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

yes, there is.

```
((i & 3) == 0)
```

Note that this may not be any faster. Also a good optimizing compiler will convert your modulus against constant 4 to the fastest operation anyway, so it may well generate this automatically.

Check the generated code if you are interested.

Comment: And it's not actually guaranteed to work by the C++ standard, although only for the rather unlikely reason that C++ implementations are permitted to use 1s' complement representation of negative integers.

Comment: I tested on GCC 4.6.3 and identical code was produced. The compiler is smart enough to know that a constant modulus that's a power of two is identical to a bitwise AND with a number one less than the modulus on that platform. (Interestingly, `andl` on x86_64 and `testb` on x86_32. Go figure.)